# How to convert a value that belongs to a range to its equivalent in another range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let's say we have the range $[0, 1]$ and the value $0.7$ that belongs to that range, how can I convert that value to its equivalent in the range $[0.8, 1]$? (or any other arbitrary range)

Could you provide examples of how to solve something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward map from $[a,b]$ to $[c,d]$ is to map $$x\mapsto \frac{x-a}{b-a}(d-c)+c$$

Comment: Does this method allow range like this [-100, 100] with a negative min?